# Extract Artworks from folder of Songs

Tags: ffmpeg, batch, batch-file, conversion, album-art

Is there a way to take a folder of music files, for example in *m4a* format, and extract all artworks into separate*jpg* files automatically? Say there are 144 songs, so without having to do it manually for every single track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using a *batch* file, that starts an *ffmpeg* command for every song:

```
:: Extract the image of an m4a file and store it as jpg
for %%i in (*.m4a) do ffmpeg -i %%i -an -vcodec copy %%i.jpg
```

Of course, input and output file formats can be changed if necessary.